# Jquery, getting 'this' selector from a conditional

Tags: javascript, jquery, checkbox, input, jquery-selectors

I have several elements on my page with the 'checkbox' class.  When clicked, a corresponding checkbox input is checked.  However, I need to have JQuery check if the checkbox element is active when the page first loads, and check the checkbox input accordingly at that time.

Since there are multiple 'checkbox' classes on my page, I used the 'this' selector previously and it worked fine, however I do not know how to make it do this with my conditional on page load without the .click action that I used before.  Here's what I'm trying to make work:

```
if($('.checkbox').hasClass('active')) {
    $('[name="'+$(this).attr('rel')+'"]').prop('checked', true); 
}
```

Obviously the 'this' selector doesn't know what I'm referring to.  Is there a better way of doing this?  Since it's checking through a bunch of elements and not just one I'm stumped.  Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can only use `this` within the context of a jQuery function, so in this scope it's not going to refer to any `.checkbox`.

You can use .each instead:

```
$('.checkbox.active').each(function() {
    // In this context, this refers to the DOM element represented by .checkbox.active
    $('[name="'+this.rel+'"]').prop('checked', true); 
});
```

Comment: FWIW, `rel` has a reflected property, so `$(this).attr('rel')` ends up being a roundabout way of writing `this.rel`. :-)

Comment: You guys are wizards.  This worked perfectly.  Thanks so much!  (I'll accept in 4 minutes when it lets me)

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Nice! I didn't realise that

Comment: If it has a reflected property, you should *probably* be using `.prop` instead of `.attr`.

Comment: @michaelb958 TJ's point is that neither prop or attr is required, as the DOM element already has an exposed `rel` property.

Comment: @RGraham Yes, that is much better. But if you (future reader) must use the jQuery way, don't use `.attr`.

Comment: @michaelb958 That's true, I've removed the reference to attr in the answer

Answer (score 4):

The `each` function may suit your needs:

```
$('.checkbox').each(function() {
    var $this = $(this);
    if ($this.hasClass('active')) {
        $('[name="'+$this.attr('rel')+'"]').prop('checked', true); 
    }
});
```

If the checkboxes must be unchecked when the `active` class is absent, then:

```
$('.checkbox').each(function() {
    var $this = $(this);
    $('[name="'+$this.attr('rel')+'"]').prop('checked', $this.hasClass('active')); 
});
```